# \setstretch resets \parindent in koma-script

Tags: spacing, koma-script, setspace

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\showthe\parindent
\setstretch{1.0}
\showthe\parindent
```

```
> 20.0pt.
> 12.0pt.
```

I have no idea where it goes wrong because koma-script recommends using `setspace`.

---

Problem details:

1. The command changes `20pt` to `12pt`, but keeps `200pt` at `200pt`.
2. Compiling with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` gives different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command `\setparsize` to change \parindent, then koma will keep track of the value

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setparsizes{20pt}{\parskip}{\parfillskip}

\begin{document}

\the\parindent

\setstretch{1.0}

\the\parindent

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems `\setparsizes` doesn't directly change `\parindent` but keeps some internal variable for setting it on a page layout update. But the doc doesn't give more details. I guess it has to be called very early.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the untimely setting of `\parindent`.

If I set it correctly, the value is preserved.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{setspace}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}}

\begin{document}

\the\parindent

\setstretch{1.0}

\the\parindent

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a problem, though: if you don't use `\AtBeginDocument`, the value is set to 11.74988pt

This doesn't happen with `article`.

Comment: I just saw this in koma-script doc: direct changes of the standard lengths `\parskip`, `\parindent` and `\parfillskip` are not only unnecessary but mostly inadvisable. I guess it wants users to use `\setparsizes` instead.